# width measurement of carbon fiber by Detectron2?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to image processing in deep learning, and my work is to measure the width of nano fibers in Scanning Electron Microscope(SEM) images.

I am wondering if I can use Detectron2 to find the area and length of the detected fibers by object detection and key-point detection, respectively, and then divide them to get the desired width.

[Here is one example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYfwQ.jpg)

I would greatly appreciate it if someone kindly give me some advice.

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem. You don’t need to identify all fibers, not complete fibers. You just need to finds parts of fibers suitable for measurement. This means that thru must be in focus, and have good contrast. Once you have done that, measuring the width can be done very precisely by interpolating along a line perpendicular to the fiber. That part is relatively simple compared to the first part.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I have tried to distinguish the fibers by binary threshold using openCV, but the accuracy is relatively low, about 30%. That's why I want to try the deep learning to improve it. Could you be more specific on "how to finds parts of fibers suitable for measurement"?

Comment: Are all of them nano-fibers? Do you need to measure the width of all those fibers in the image? Sorry, I have no idea about nano-fibers.